# How to use keras ImageDataGenerator flow_from_directory given a map from image name to class label?

Tags: image-processing, keras, tensorflow2.0

Folder's structure is like following:

```
-dataset
   |---train_set
   |      |-- img01.jpg
   |      |-- img02.jpg
   |      |-.....
   |
   |---val_set
```

I don't have subfolders in train_set whose name is class label. However I have a dictionary from image name to class label like `map = {'img01.jpg': 10, 'img02.jpg': 3, 'img03.jpg':12, ...}`

How to use keras' `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory` in this case, since it requires me to sort the images in different subfolders?  My training set's volume is around 500 G, it's not convenient to build subfolders according to classes' labels. If I cannot use `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory`, is there any alternative way to realize this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Keras ImageDataGenerator class also offers [flow_from_dataframe()](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_dataframe) method, that should do the job.

Check out this [tutorial](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/keras-imagedatagenerator-methods-an-easy-guide-550ecd3c0a92) (second part) for your case example.